# Graph API: Upload small item to OneDrive fails with error 504

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, office365, onedrive

I am trying to upload a small item (size less than 4 MB) to OneDrive. It was working perfectly fine till a few days back but now I am consistently seeing 504 error.

I am using Graph APIs and JSON batching to upload to OneDrive. The same code works with other tenants but is failing for this particular tenant for the last 4/5 days.

Please note that the download of items and upload of large items (size greater than 4 MB) works perfectly fine.

Please let me know if anyone has any idea about this issue.

Error response I am getting below:

```
{"responses": [
   {
       "id": "1",
       "status":504,
       "headers" : {
          "Content-Type":"application/json"},
          "body":"ew0KICAiZXJyb3IiOiB7DQogICAgImNvZGUiOiAiVW5r
                  bm93bkVycm9yIiwNCiAgICAibWVzc2FnZSI6ICIiLA0KICAgICJp
                  bm5lckVycm9yIjogew0KICAgICAgImRhdGUiOiAiMjAyMC0xMi0
                  yOFQxMDo1NDo1NyIsDQogICAgICAicmVxdWVzdC1pZCI6ICJjMmYzYWFmNi1lZj
                  EyLTRhZTMtOWUwYy0yMTI5ZTJhZTg4ZDEiLA0KICAgICAgImNsa
                  WVudC1yZXF1ZXN0LWlkIjogImMyZjNhYWY2LWVmMTItNGFlMy0
                  5ZTBjLTIxMjllMmFlODhkMSINCiAgICB9DQogIH0NCn0="},
        {
           "id": "2","status":424,
           "body":{
                 "error": {
                 "code": "FailedDependency",
                 "message": "Request failed as dependent request failed",
                 "innerError": {
                    "date": "2020-12-28T10:54:57",
                    "request-id": "c2f3aaf6-ef12-4ae3-9e0c-2129e2ae88d1",
                    "client-request-id": "c2f3aaf6-ef12-4ae3-9e0c-2129e2ae88d1"
               }
             }
```

I am sending the request after encoding the body to Base 64 format. The Base 64 text in the above response translates to the following:

```
{
    "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "",
    "innerError": {
              "date": "2020-12-28T10:54:57",
              "request-id": "c2f3aaf6-ef12-4ae3-9e0c-2129e2ae88d1",
              "client-request-id": "c2f3aaf6-ef12-4ae3-9e0c-2129e2ae88d1"
     }
 }
```

}

Comment: If you get 503 or 504 errors, there is a possibility that you are being throttling due to high load: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/errors. 503 and 504 errors are not being mentioned in the MS throttling guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/throttling, since they are not directly the client's fault. However, applying the same principles in the guide, such as a retry policy or preventing request peaks, will help you deal with these errors. That being said, it is between Christmas and New Year, so it could also be a maintenance related issue.

Comment: I have tried the retry option and it has not helped. If it's a maintenance issue I wonder how users in the field are experiencing this and what workaround they are using.

Comment: Ok you're using JSON batching and you see the error. If you used two different calls, then figure out which call is leading to this. Test the same with Graph Explorer or POSTMAN, isolate the issue and try to handle it. I know 503/504 are related servers, but keep in mind that you should use the JSON batching and not hitting its [limitations as described in the documentation, due to that you might be seeing this error.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#json-batching)